# Codeigniter - dynamic right menu

Tags: codeigniter

i have a right menu in my ci blog site that contains categories and no. of post that is subjected to change, has the following format,

```
Categories:
   Science(24)
   education(32)
    ....
    ....
```

the number is brackets is the total amount of post in that category.

my template file is here:

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');

$this->load->view($main_content);

$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

And my right menu is in the footer file.
How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you better have a main view divided into divs(header, main_content,footer,right_menu) always loaded and load each view in the appropriate div.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="top_menu">
                <?php $this->load->view('top_menu'); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="main_content">
                <?php $this->load->view('main_content'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this system for including header/footer etc:

```
<?php

/**
 * /application/core/MY_Loader.php
 *
 */
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        $content  = $this->view('templates/header', $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->view('templates/footer', $vars, $return);

        if ($return)
        {
            return $content;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, this is all you have to do:

```
<?php
$this->load->template('body');
```

Code if from user: landons